# Solder won't stick to iron

Tags: soldering

So, I bought my first soldering iron. (I used trafo until now..) It was pretty cheap, wasn't expecting much from it. Wanted to try it out, but the tip turned black. (Picture included, sorry for the quality.) I used Flux before trying to get a bit of tin on the tip, but the tin just wouldn't stick! Instead, it melted and fell off. 
I have replaceable tips, I somehow knew I'm going to mess it up. But I don't want to make the same mistake. Any help? 
[image: soldering tip]

Comment: take some sand paper to the tip when cold until you see clean metal on all sides, reheat and IMMEDIATELY re-tin the tip. Then be careful not to leave it on too long, always remember to tin the tip and clean with brass wool frequently.

Comment: no problemo! even the cheapest irons can be pretty effective if you take care of them properly!